# Unable to create Shipment by code - Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I trying to create shipment by code in Acumatica, it's working fine with Inventory item without Serial Number but im getting this error with item with serial number

> ```
> **PX.Data.PXRowPersistingException: 'SO Error: One or more lines have unassigned slots and / or lot / serial number**
> ```

i m using this code to create the shipment:

```
SOShipmentEntrysoShipmentGraph=PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();
soShipmentGraph.Clear();
DocumentList<SOShipment>created=newDocumentList<SOShipment>(soShipmentGraph);
SOShipmentsOShipment=newSOShipment();
created.Add(sOShipment);
soShipmentGraph.CreateShipment(newOrder,5,newOrder.OrderDate,true,SOOperation.Issue,created);
```

what i m missing ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have enough inventory to fill the SO line qty.  The CreateShipment API tried to allocate 5 widgets for example and found only 4 available Serial numbers.    You should look up the inventory item and confirm that sufficient qtys exist.

Comment: I have sufficient qtys but the problem is i need to affect the serial number to the shipline by code and i dont know how to do it with the code i'm using

Comment: The List of SOShipments variable you create and use as a parameter with the CreateShipment call will contain the successfully created shipment after a successful execution.  I would create a SOShipmentEntry graph and set this to the current value.  Then you'll have to drill down to SOShipLineSplit in order to change the allocation.